# How to allow user to use application only if they tweet about it. (php/jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, twitter

Is there a quick & easy way to setup an application to allow a user to use it if they tweet about you?  Maybe click a button, it auto tweets and they can move forward in the application.  Is there an application that makes this KISS simple, or do I have to start logging through the twitter API?

Use Case:

User Logs onto website & inputs email.
Popup:  Tweet about us to use the application for free.
User tweets & continues through application.

Comment: There are plenty of ways, but I don't think that anyone will help you make your clients spam about you.

Comment: I'm not sure it's Spam.  This what AppSumo did a few weeks ago when they were giving away free products in exchange for a Tweet.

Answer (score 2):

You can't tweet into someone's account without them first logging into your application through OAuth. You also can't tweet into someone's account when they do log in without their prior permission. That would be a violation of the Twitter TOS.

But you can help someone tweet about you without them logging in first. If you create a hyperlink with the URL form:

http://twitter.com/?status=[the text you want them to tweet]

When they click this link, the text you want them to tweet will be in the status box on their Twitter page. If they then click the tweet button, the tweet will be sent. You can use the search API to watch for these tweets, and do whatever you want to reward that user.

This is not spam, since the user chooses to send it. Not you. But it may be offensive, and it may get Twitter upset, if it happens too much.